# Getting SSL Connection Error on MySql.Data 8.0.26

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql.data

So I've been using the MySql.Data from NuGet for a long time for connecting with my MariaDB databases in a lot of different .NET projects. It happens that now I'm starting a new .NET5 project and to start fresh just installed the last version 8.0.26 of the MySql.Data package, but when trying to connect to the database I'm getting the following error:

> > MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException   HResult=0x80004005   Message=SSL Connection error.   Source=MySql.Data   StackTrace:    at
> > MySql.Data.Common.Ssl.StartSSL(Stream& baseStream, Encoding encoding,
> > String connectionString)    at
> > MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()    at
> > MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()    at
> > MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
> > settings)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    at
> > MySqlSSLErrorTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> > C:\Users\Murillo\source\repos\MySqlSSLErrorTest\MySqlSSLErrorTest\Program.cs:line
> > 16
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync(TIOAdapter)
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.Result.get()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync(TIOAdapter,
> bool, byte[], bool)
>
> Inner Exception 1: AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
> (Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.)
>
> Inner Exception 2: IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a
> corrupted frame was received.

Now, as I've been searching, it seems that the version 8.0.26 it's comming with some changes as stated [here at the MySql website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-26.html#mysqld-8-0-26-deprecation-removal) regarding this issue (maybe?), but I haven't been able to understand what exactly are the changes I need to make to my Connection String to make it work.

Here I leave a very simple Console App example to reproduce the error:

```
class Program
{
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("DATABASE=myDB; data source=localhost; user=root; PASSWORD=pass; POOLING=FALSE;");

        con.Open(); //ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I can downgrade the package to an older version to make it work, but I would like to understand how to solve this issue in order to be up to date with the latest features.

Thanks!

Comment: The [MariaDB pages](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlconnector-for-adonet/) point to an alternate .NET connector that appears current.

Comment: The TLS changes you linked to are in version 8.0.26 of MySQL Server itself, not the MySql.Data package. I suspect the issue might be with using MySql.Data on .NET 5.0; in my experience it's not as well-tested on .NET Core. I'd suggest trying out https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ (disclaimer: lead author) in your .NE 5.0 project and seeing if that works better.

Comment: Thanks Bradley. It's nice to have some feedback from the author. As danblack sugested, I installed MySqlConnector and it worked perfectly as it was with the past versions of MySql.Data. To be honest, I'd never had a problem with MySql.Data until now, but since I'm using mainly MariaDB now and they are slowly starting to diverge from MySQL, I think I'll definetly give a try to MySQLConnector, especially when it seems best suited and even recomended by the MariaDB team aswell. Again, many thanks to you both.